# c# how to decide whether to add to sub-list or start new one

Tags: c#

I have an sql query that provides me my data where I sometimes have lines that should be clustered (the data is aligned with an order by). The data is grouped by the field CAPName. Going through those rows line by line, I need to decide whether a new list should be initiated (content of CAPName differs to previous itteration), or whether the (already) initated list (from the previous iteration) should be added, too.

My pain lays with the location of the declaration of the relatedCapabilitySystem list. 
I wanted to declare it within the if statement (Because, as I stated I need to decide whether the list from the previous iteration should be added too, or whether it should start a new list), but I can't as the compiler throws an exception, as the `RLCapSys.Add(rCs);` is non-existing in this content (which is only theoretically true). I understand why the compiler throws this exception. But if I declare the list on a "higher" level, than I always have a new list, which I don't want in the case that the item should be added to the list defined in the iteration(s) (1 or more) before

So what I want to achieve is, generate the list RLCapSys and add to it, in case the previous iteration contains the same CAPName (for clustering), otherwise create a new list.

```
SqlCommand cmdDetail = new SqlCommand(SQL_SubSytemsToCapability, DBConDetail);
SqlDataReader rdrDetail = cmdDetail.ExecuteReader();

List<relatedCapility> RLCaps = new List<relatedCapility>();
string lastCapShown = null;

while (rdrDetail.Read())
{
    List<relatedCapabilitySystem> RLCapSys = new List<relatedCapabilitySystem>();
    if (lastCapShown != rdrDetail["CAPName"].ToString())
    {
        //List<relatedCapabilitySystem> RLCapSys2 = new List<relatedCapabilitySystem>();
        relatedCapility rC = new relatedCapility
        {
            Capability = rdrDetail["CAPName"].ToString(),
            systemsRelated = RLCapSys,

        };
        RLCaps.Add(rC);
    }

    relatedCapabilitySystem rCs = new relatedCapabilitySystem
    {
        system = rdrDetail["name"].ToString(),
        start = rdrDetail["SysStart"].ToString(),
        end = rdrDetail["SysEnd"].ToString(),
    };
    RLCapSys.Add(rCs);

    // method to compare the last related Capability shown create a new related Capabilty entry or add to the existing releated Capabilty related system list
    lastCapShown = rdrDetail["CAPName"].ToString();

}
DBConDetail.Close();
```

and for reason of completness (but I think it is not needed here):

```
internal class CapabilitiesC
{
    public List<Capability>Capabilities{ get;set;}
}

public class Capability
{
    public string name { get; internal set; }
    public string tower { get; internal set; }
    public string color { get; internal set; }
    public List<relatedCapility> related { get; set; }
}

public class relatedCapility
{
    public string Capability { get; set; }
    public List<relatedCapabilitySystem> systemsRelated { get; set; }
}

public class relatedCapabilitySystem
{
    public string system { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string end { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working now. Thx everyone for your help. 
@martin, thx for your solution, you have put quite some effort into this, but that would have required for me to completely re-write my code. I am sure your approach would work and will be my next approach should I have a similar problem again.
It was a combination of the other answers that helped me figure it out. Let me show you what I ended up with:

```
            SqlCommand cmdDetail = new SqlCommand(SQL_SubSytemsToCapability, DBConDetail);
            SqlDataReader rdrDetail = cmdDetail.ExecuteReader();

            List<relatedCapility> RLCaps = new List<relatedCapility>();
            List<relatedCapabilitySystem> RLCapSys = new List<relatedCapabilitySystem>();

            string lastCapShown = null;
            while (rdrDetail.Read())
            {

                if (lastCapShown != rdrDetail["CAPName"].ToString())
                {
                    RLCapSys = relatedCapabilitySystemList();
                    relatedCapility rC = new relatedCapility
                    {
                        Capability = rdrDetail["CAPName"].ToString(),
                        systemsRelated = RLCapSys,
                    };
                    RLCaps.Add(rC);
                }

                relatedCapabilitySystem rCs = new relatedCapabilitySystem
                {
                    system = rdrDetail["name"].ToString(),
                    start = rdrDetail["SysStart"].ToString(),
                    end = rdrDetail["SysEnd"].ToString(),
                };

                RLCapSys.Add(rCs);

                // method to compare the last related Capability shown create a new related Capabilty entry or add to the existing releated Capabilty related system list
                lastCapShown = rdrDetail["CAPName"].ToString();

            }
            DBConDetail.Close();
```

So that's the section already shown bevor including my changes. Plus I added this:

```
        private List<relatedCapabilitySystem> relatedCapabilitySystemList()
    {
        List<relatedCapabilitySystem> RLCapSys = new List<relatedCapabilitySystem>();
        return RLCapSys;
    }
```

Now I have new list reference everytime the CapName changes that is then added to the "higher" list. Before I had the issue of the very same list repeatedly assigned rather than a fresh one started. 
So thx again for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of your code is to take the input data and group it by capability. However, that is not immediately obvious. You can change your code to use LINQ so it becomes easier to understand and in the process solving your problem.

First you need a type to represent a record in your database. For lack of better name I will use `Record`:

```
class Record
{
    public string System { get; set; }
    public string Start { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }
    public string Capabilty { get; set; }
}
```

You can then create an iterator block to return all the records from the database (using an OR mapper like Entity Framework avoids most of this code and you can even shift some of the work from your computer to the database server):

```
IEnumerable<Record> GetRecords()
{
    // Code to create connection and command (preferably in a using statement)
    SqlDataReader rdrDetail = cmdDetail.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdrDetail.Read())
    {
        yield return new Record {
            System = rdrDetail["name"].ToString(),
            Start = rdrDetail["SysStart"].ToString(),
            End = rdrDetail["SysEnd"].ToString(),
            Capability = rdrDetail["CAPName"].ToString()
        };
    }
    // Close connection (proper using statement will do this)
}
```

Finally, you can use LINQ to perform the grouping:

```
var RLCaps = GetRecords()
    .GroupBy(
        record => record.Capability,
        (capability, records) => new relatedCapility
            {
                Capability = capability ,
                systemsRelated = records
                    .Select(record => new relatedCapabilitySystem
                        {
                            system = record.System,
                            start = record.Start,
                            end = record.End
                        })
                    .ToList()
            })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just assign it as NULL. The pattern would be

```
List<> myList = null;
if(condition)
{
    myList = new List<>();
}
else
{
    myList = previousList;
}   
myList.Add();
previousList = myList;
```

Comment: Thx for the hint, I forgot to mention this ;) 
I already tried this by adding the list above the while loop. I added 'List<relatedCapabilitySystem> RLCapSys = null;' but that creates an exception in the if statement. Which reads: "A local or parameter named 'RLCapSys' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter.

Comment: @Janbro: You don't get an exception. You get a compile error because you declare a list variable with the same name twice with the code  `List<relatedCapabilitySystem> RLCapSys = null;` in nested blocks. You should remove the inner declaration. If you at that point need to assign `null` to the list (I don't think so) you should use the code `RLCapSys = null;`. This will assign `null` to the variable you declared outside the loop.